# python filter + multiprocessing + iterator lazy loading

Tags: python, filter, python-multiprocessing, lazy-evaluation

I have a 2 dimensional array which produces a huge (>300GB) list of combinations, so i'd like to do lazy iteration on the iterator produced by itertools.combinations and parallelize this operation. The problem is that I need to filter the output and this isn't supported by Multiprocessing. My existing workaround for this requires loading the combinations list into memory, which also doesn't work because of the size of the list.

```
n_nodes = np.random.randn(10, 100)
cutoff=0.3

def node_combinations(nodes):
    return itertools.combinations(list(range(len(nodes))), 2)    

def pfilter(func, candidates):
    return np.asarray([c for c, keep in zip(candidates, pool.map(func, candidates)) if keep])

def pearsonr(xy: tuple):
    correlation_coefficient = scipy.stats.pearsonr(n_nodes[xy[0]], n_nodes[xy[1]])[0]
    if correlation_coefficient >= cutoff:
            return True
        else:
            return False


edgelist = pfilter(pearsonr, node_combinations(n_nodes))
```

I'm looking for a way to do lazy evaluation of a large iterator using multiprocessing with filter instead of map.

Comment: "I need to filter the output and this isn't supported by Multiprocessing" what do you mean?

Comment: `filter` method can't be parallelized using multiprocessing package

Comment: what if you share the generator across different processes and then filter the data?

Comment: Filter can be done with multiprocessing just return either [a] or [] from the map function and then flatten. But you should use `pool.imap` and you will need to slow down the over eager pool thread by either a proper fix or the semaphore hack. Otherwise it will expand the job queue faster than the tasks can be processed. I was going to write a proper fix as both 27 and 38 have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses a Semaphore to slow down the over eager pool thread. Not the proper solution as it doesn't fix the other issues such as that nested loops that use the same pool and loop over the result of imap have their outer loop's jobs finish before any of the inner loops jobs even get to start. But it does limit the memory usage:

```
def slowdown(n=16):
    s = threading.Semaphore(n)
    def inner(it):
        for item in it:
            s.acquire()
            yield item
    def outer(it):
        for item in it:
            s.release()
            yield item
    return outer, inner
```

This is used to wrap `pool.imap` as such:

```
outer, inner = slowdown()
outer(pool.imap(func, inner(candidates)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoxha's suggestion works fine -- thanks!

@Dan the issue is that even empty lists take up memory, which x42 billion pairings is nearly 3TB in memory.

here's my implementation:

```
import more_itertools
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import scipy
from tqdm import tqdm

n_nodes = np.random.randn(10, 100)
num_combinations = int((int(n_nodes.shape[0]) ** 2) - int(n_nodes.shape[0]) // 2)
cpu_count = 8
cutoff=0.3

def node_combinations(nodes):
    return itertools.combinations(list(range(len(nodes))), 2)    

def edge_gen(xy_iterator: type(itertools.islice)):
    edges = []
    for cand in tqdm(xy_iterator, total=num_combinations//cpu_count)
        if pearsonr(cand):
            edges.append(cand)

def pearsonr(xy: tuple):
    correlation_coefficient = scipy.stats.pearsonr(n_nodes[xy[0]], n_nodes[xy[1]])[0]
    if correlation_coefficient >= cutoff:
            return True
        else:
            return False


slices = more_itertools.distribute(cpu_count), node_combinations(n_nodes))
pool = mp.Pool(cpu_count)
results = pool.imap(edge_gen, slices)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Sure. If they aren't consumed faster than they are produced. I left the function returning a boolean because there was no point in passing the tuple twice. The overhead of doubling the pickling didn't make sense. The issue with the over eager pool is real. Try running `for r in pool.imap(identity, itertools.count()): pass` and look at the memory usage increase over time.